# R xml tree parse using XML tree parse

Tags: r, xml

I'm new to R and I'm trying to read and load the XML document at the URL (http://www.cs.washington.edu/research/xmldatasets/data/auctions/ebay.xml) using the [`XML::xmlTreeParse()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/XML/versions/3.98-1.16/topics/xmlTreeParse) function like so:

```r
# load necessary packages ---
library(XML)
library(RCurl)

# load necessary data ----
u <- "http://aiweb.cs.washington.edu/research/projects/xmltk/xmldata/data/auctions/ebay.xml"

# convert XML file to an R structure representing the XML/HTML tree
xml.file <- xmlTreeParse(getURL(u), useInternalNodes = TRUE)
```

but I get this error message:

```
Error: 1: Space required after the Public Identifier
2: SystemLiteral " or ' expected
3: SYSTEM or PUBLIC, the URI is missing
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: where u is the variable I saved the url as.

Answer (score 1):

It's generally bad form to hit that URL over-and-over-and-over again since the content isn't going to change. It's small-is but bandwidth and CPU time isn't free for anyone. Said network pulls may be the issue for you as well (it looks like the in-memory download is only a partial download).

We can use `httr` to avoid Windows issues with `download.file()` and get built-in caching (by default it won't download more than once if the target local file exists):

```
library(httr)
library(XML)
library(xml2)

xml_url <- "https://aiweb.cs.washington.edu/research/projects/xmltk/xmldata/data/auctions/ebay.xml.gz"
```

Stay organized by storing things in well-named locations locally:

```
dir.create("~/Data/xmldata/auctions", recursive = TRUE)

xml_fil <- file.path("~/Data/xmldata/auctions", basename(xml_url))
```

Get the file (using the `gz` one out of respect for their bandwidth and knowing both the `XML` and `xml2` packages can read it just fine):

```
httr::GET(url = xml_url, httr::write_disk(xml_fil))
## Response [https://aiweb.cs.washington.edu/research/projects/xmltk/xmldata/data/auctions/ebay.xml.gz]
##   Date: 2018-10-09 08:47
##   Status: 200
##   Content-Type: application/x-gzip
##   Size: 11 kB
## <ON DISK>  /Users/bob/data/xmldata/auctions/ebay.xml.gz
```

With `XML`:

```
using_XML <- XML::xmlTreeParse(xml_fil, useInternalNodes = TRUE)

using_XML
## <?xml version="1.0"?>
## <!DOCTYPE root SYSTEM "http://www.cs.washington.edu/research/projects/xmltk/xmldata/data/auctions/ebay.dtd">
## <root>
##   <listing>
##     <seller_info>
##       <seller_name> cubsfantony</seller_name>
##       <seller_rating> 848</seller_rating>
## ... goes on ...
```

With `xml2`:

```
using_xml2 <- xml2::read_xml(xml_fil)

using_xml2
## {xml_document}
## <root>
## [1] <listing>\n  <seller_info>\n    <seller_name> cubsfantony</seller_na ...
## [2] <listing>\n  <seller_info>\n    <seller_name> ct-inc</seller_name>\n ...
## [3] <listing>\n  <seller_info>\n    <seller_name> ct-inc</seller_name>\n ...
## [4] <listing>\n  <seller_info>\n    <seller_name>bestbuys4systems </sell ...
## [5] <listing>\n  <seller_info>\n    <seller_name> sales@ctgcom.com</sell ...
```

Answer (score 0):

## Overall

After loading both the [`XML`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/XML/versions/3.98-1.16) and [`RCurl`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RCurl/versions/1.95-4.11) packages, I was able to run the code without an error message. It might be the case that we're using two different versions of each package, so I'm including my session info down at the bottom.

### Code

```r
# load necessary packages ---
library(XML)   # XML_3.98-1.16 
library(RCurl) # RCurl_1.95-4.11

# load necessary data ----
u <- "http://aiweb.cs.washington.edu/research/projects/xmltk/xmldata/data/auctions/ebay.xml"

# convert XML file to an R structure representing the XML/HTML tree
xml.file <- xmlTreeParse(getURL(u), useInternalNodes = TRUE)

# check class of xml.file
class(xml.file) # [1] "XMLInternalDocument" "XMLAbstractDocument"

# end of script #
```

### Session Info

```r
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

other attached packages:
[1] RCurl_1.95-4.11 bitops_1.0-6    XML_3.98-1.16  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.19      pillar_1.3.0      compiler_3.5.1   
 [4] plyr_1.8.4        bindr_0.1.1       viridis_0.5.1    
 [7] tools_3.5.1       digest_0.6.17     evaluate_0.11    
[10] tibble_1.4.2      gtable_0.2.0      viridisLite_0.3.0
[13] pkgconfig_2.0.2   rlang_0.2.2       rstudioapi_0.8   
[16] yaml_2.2.0        bindrcpp_0.2.2    gridExtra_2.3    
[19] stringr_1.3.1     dplyr_0.7.6       knitr_1.20       
[22] rprojroot_1.3-2   grid_3.5.1        tidyselect_0.2.4 
[25] glue_1.3.0        R6_2.2.2          rmarkdown_1.10   
[28] ggplot2_3.0.0     purrr_0.2.5       magrittr_1.5     
[31] backports_1.1.2   scales_1.0.0      htmltools_0.3.6  
[34] assertthat_0.2.0  colorspace_1.3-2  stringi_1.2.4    
[37] lazyeval_0.2.1    munsell_0.5.0     crayon_1.3.4
```